# Не могу вывести номер первого столбца матрицы, состоящего из отрицательных элементов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь вывеси номер первого столбца состоящего из отрицательных элементов,но выводится номер первого отрицательного элемента, не могу понять как решить проблему

```
Idx = -1

j = 0
for j in range(n):
    i=0
    while (i<n) and (Idx == -1):
        if A[i][j] < 0:
            Idx = i
        i=i+1
return Idx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

алгоритм должен быть такой:

1. пройти по всем столбцам матрицы
2. проверить каждый столбец на наличие отрицательных элементов (точнее - проверить на наличие неотрицательных элементов - если найдены - столбец отвергается и анализируется следующий столбец)
3. при нахождении столбца - выдать его номер

т.е. по хорошему код должен быть таким:

```
def find(matrix, cols, rows):
    for col in range(cols):
        is_success = True
        for row in range(rows):
            if matrix[row][col] >= 0:
                is_success = False
                break
        if is_success:
            return col
    return -1
```

можно чуть покороче, но и менее производительнее:

```
def find(matrix, cols, rows):
    for col in range(cols):
        if [row for row in range(rows) if matrix[row][col] >= 0] == []:
            return col
    return -1
```

или так, что красивее :)

```
def find(matrix, cols, rows):
    for col in range(cols):
        if any(True for row in range(rows) if matrix[row][col] >= 0):
            return col
    return -1
```

или так:

```
if all(matrix[row][col] < 0 for row in range(rows)):
    return col
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, очень помогли!